# Is it possible to get the Parameter names from a PDO Prepared Statement

Tags: php, pdo

I have a prepared query, say

```
SELECT * FROM userSignLog WHERE userID = :uid AND userStatus = :status
```

Where, value for :uid and :status will be passed along with other values in my $_POST array.

Now, i want to pass (or Bind) only :uid and :status for my current query, dynamically. I was iterating through the entire $_POST array, taking the $_POST[name] as parameter name and bind the declared parameter with value of $_POST[name].

While executing, PHP throws below error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

If i can somehow manage to get the List of Token names from the prepared statement, i can take only those values from my POST array, bind and execute the query. I am willing to know if it is possible to get the list from a prepared statement?

Answer (score 3):

You could, possibly capture the output of [`PDOStatement::debugDumpParams()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php). There is an example of the output on the linked page.

For example:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userSignLog WHERE userID = :uid AND userStatus = :status";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$uid = 'testUid';
$status = 'testStatus';
$statement->bindParam('uid', $uid);
$statement->bindParam('status', $status);
ob_start();
$statement->debugDumpParams();
$params = ob_get_clean();
var_dump($params);
```

Gives the following output:-

```
string 'SQL: [70] SELECT * FROM userSignLog WHERE userID = :uid AND userStatus = :status
Params:  2
Key: Name: [4] :uid
paramno=-1
name=[4] ":uid"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [7] :status
paramno=-1
name=[7] ":status"
is_param=1
param_type=2
' (length=240)
```

The information you want is in there, it is just a matter of digging it out.

I'm not sure how effective this would be, although it is the only reference I can find to the information you are looking to access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i understood "debugDumpParams()" would return the dump of the entire prepared statement. I am specifically looking for how to get only the list of the parameters in the query??

Comment: Yes, but the list of parameters is in there. I'll edit in an example.

Answer (score 2):

As PDO supports an OOP style interface you are free to overwrite the PDOStatement class, espcially the methods `bindValue` and `exec` in order to generate that info. Also you would add a method `getParams()`.

To make PDO use your custom statement class you need to issue:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('CustomStatement', array($pdo)));
```